# How to clear contents of multiple <input>s by one button

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="A" id="A" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="B" id="B" autocomplete="off"/>

<button class="smallbutton" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('input').value = ''">Clear</button>
```

I tried using `getElementsByTagName` but it doesn't seem to work. What else needs to be done? Or what else can be done besides `TagName`?

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a node list. You need to iterate

Comment: Also if in a form, add type="reset" to the button tag

Comment: Better alternative to getElementsByWhatever is document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score -1):

```html
<input type="text" value="John"><br><br>
<input type="text" value="Doe"><br><br>

<button class="smallbutton" onclick="[...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')].forEach(input => input.value = '')">Clear</button>
```